# Laptop not charging when connected to mains outlet

Tags: laptop, charger

I've had this laptop for a few weeks now, it's a Sony Vaio.

I went to charge it a few days ago and plugged in the power cable, but it's not charging. The battery icon in the Windows taskbar to the bottom right says it's plugged in and charging, but the charge level never goes above 2%. I have checked and I don't have a hcarging switch on the laptop anywhere, so it should be charging.

If I unplug the cable, the laptop runs out of power within 30 seconds or so, further fueling my thought that it's a faulty battery.

Anyone have any bright ideas? If this doesn't get fixed I'll just ring up Sony and get them to send me a replacement battery or something.

Thanks.

Comment: get a replacement immediately, your battery is faulty

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a faulty battery or charging cicuitry.  One thing to try is to remove the battery, check the contacts on the battery and in the laptop where the battery goes.  It may be unlikely, but possibly there is some contamination there.

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to me with a Lenovo laptop.

It turns out the problem was a faulty battery.

Laptop batteries are notorious for wearing out long before you'd expect them to.

Unfortunately, if you take your laptop to an authorized Sony repair shop, they will charge you a fee to tell you what is wrong.

If you know someone who has the same model of laptop you can try their battery to see if it works, verifying the problem is the battery.

Alternately, you could take a risk and buy a new battery to see if that fixes the problem.